# Google sheets custom function that uses Youtube API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, youtube-data-api

I'm looking for a way how to retrieve the channel name, given Youtube video ID. Here's an apps script that works, if I run it in the code editor (I get correct output in console).

```
function GET_CHANNEL_TITLE(videoId) {
  const v = YouTube.Videos.list("snippet", {id: videoId});
  const itemCount = v.items.length;
  if (itemCount == 1) {
    //Logger.log(v.items[0].snippet.channelTitle);
    return v.items[0].snippet.channelTitle;
  } else if (itemCount > 1) {
    //Logger.log("Too many videos found");
    return "";
  } else {
    //Logger.log("Video not found");
    return "";
  }
}
```

However, I get an error if I try to call it as a custom worksheet function: `Error GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.videos.list failed with error: The request is missing a valid API key. (line 2).`

How the API key should be provided in the apps script? Should that be my API key — if so, then I have to find a way how to hide it from prying eyes? Or, it's the API key of a user who has opened the sheet - then there probably should be some OAuth routine where user is asked to authenticate and give access to Youtube API.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, YouTube API cannot be used with the custom function. In your situation, are there threads useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62205747 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/66396605

Comment: [Apps Scrips Service for Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services)

Comment: @Tanaike thank you, the Web App wrapper solution works, but is very slow. But then again, I shouldn't expect a great speed from Google Sheets + HTTP API call pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `the Web App wrapper solution works, but is very slow.`, it's yes. I apologize for this. So, I had also proposed "Workaround 1:". [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62206807) In the current stage, when the process cost is considered, using Web Apps with the custom function might not suitable.